# Generate script block containing custom language at runtime

Tags: javascript, html

I'm including a funky script (from the german social network VZ) in my page which requires me to insert a script block containing a custom "language":

```
<script type="vz/login">
    client_id : c47a1d7f134b88c9f12448e08f2ef7289e9fc8
    redirect_uri : http://game.example.com/vzcallback.html
    callback : logResponse
    fields : emails,gender,birthday
</script>
```

Can I insert such a block into my page at runtime using Javascript (no PHP or other server-side code)? I need this to set `client_id` dynamically.

Additionally I also need to insert something like:

```
<script src="https://secure.studivz.net/Js/id/v4/library.js" 
    data-authority="platform-redirect.vz-modules.net/r"
    data-authorityssl="platform-redirect.vz-modules.net/r" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

But I don't think adding those `data-`attributes will be a hard challenge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

```
var el = document.createElement("script");
el.setAttribute("type","vz/login");
el.innerHTML = "client_id : "+new_client_id
               +"\nredirect_uri : http://game.example.com/vzcallback.html"
               +"\ncallback : logResponse"
               +"\nfields : emails,gender,birthday";
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

For the second snipped use

```
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'https://secure.studivz.net/Js/id/v4/library.js';
newScript.setAttribute("data-authority","platform-redirect.vz-modules.net/r");
newScript.setAttribute("data-authorityssl", "platform-redirect.vz-modules.net/r");
headID.appendChild(newScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the vz/login script node to the dom at runtime. But you need to ensure that the vz/login node has been added *before* the JS that is looking for it.